# What is a hibernation partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have noticed the msata SSD of an ultrabook I've used has been used as hibernation partition as can be seen from *disc managment* in Windows 7. Unfortunately I can't figure out its purpose.

What is the hibernation partition for?

Comment: [Related reading](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/274540-can-windows-7-use-hibernate-partition.html)

Comment: What has your research effort shown?

Comment: @Moab I have [searched](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+hibernation+patition) for it and found one result that says it is used for the obvious reason: writing the memory content to a file in the partition when going into hibernation. I still do not really understand why this needs a separate partition.